# User Inputting multiple form fiields to retrieve related records from mysql table through php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html>
    <form action="search_book.php" method="post">
        Title:<input type="text" name="title"><br>
        Author:<input type="text" name="author"><br>
        Price of Book:<input type="text" name="price"><input type="radio"    name="radio" id="less"><Label for="less">Less Than</label><input type="radio" name="radio" id="more"><label for ="more">More Than</label<<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</html>
```

I have used an `if/else if` statement and post function when user searches either by title, author or price(html form fields) for records in a mysql table. My if/else if statement that is based on user inputting one form field at a time:

```
if($_POST['title']!="" && $_POST['title']!=" "){
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from book where Title='$title'");
} else if($_POST['author']!=""&& $_POST['author']!=" "){
    $title=$_POST['author'];
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from book where Author='$author'");
} else if($_POST['price']!="" && $_POST['price']!=" "){
    $title=$_POST['price'];
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from book where Price='$price'");
}
```

I need to take it to the next level now and want to know:

1. How do I retrieve table records if the user inputs two or three fields and not just one(eg. author and price or author and title)
2. Near the 'price' text field I need to add two radio buttons which will allow the user to check less than or more than the price he inputs in the textbox for price

Comment: can u post your html also?

Comment: Vicky, I added the html

Comment: ok let me check i'll come back to u after some tym

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Use the Below code it will work for all
   $condition=""; 
   if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) { 
     if(trim($_POST['title'])!="") {
        $condition.="Title='".$_POST['title']."' AND "; 
     }
    if(trim($_POST['author'])!="") {
      $condition.="Author='".$_POST['author']."' AND "; 
    }
    if(trim($_POST['price'])!="") {
       $condition.="Price='".$_POST['price']."' AND "; 
    }
      // remove last AND 
      if($condition!="") {
          $condition=" WHERE ".substr($condition,0,-5); 
      }

     $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from book".$condition); 
  }
```

// It will work

Comment: `$_POST` variable is always set by default, there's no need to do `isset($_POST)`